# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Wordpress3.1 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having problems with the themes I activate in Wordpress, I'm using version 3.1 [ due to hosting service limitations]

The theme fails loading slider on the home page, and it fails manipulating theme options. Specifically I am working with Parabola theme. In the Dashboard > Theme options (Parabola Settings), the accordion gets stuck and it doesn't open the option panels.

When I check browser console (chrome) it shows the next message: (at the dashboard page)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined   
media_upload (anonymous function) b.extend.ready u
```

This refers to: admin.js file

(at the homepage)

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function) b.extend.ready u
```

This refers to: frontend.js

I have seen many issues about $() and jquery() no conflict mode, I don't know if this is my case, I have checked these two files and they don't seem to be using $ shorcut.

Is there any other file I need to check, How could I fix this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: you might as well change hosting provider....no excuse for not updating php if you ask them to (i assume this is why they limit wp version) and its a shared server, if not update yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is with the version of jQuery that your site is loading. Every wordpress version comes packed with a version, and because you are using an old wordpress version, it comes with an old jQuery version.

To change the version of jQuery you can do this:

open functions.php and add this

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {      
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

It will load jQuery from googleapis. You can adjust the version you want to make your theme work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. 
I just did what Bojan Petkovski comments, and it worked only for the website pages! but still it's failing in the admin dashboard! is there a way to change jquery version for the side of the admin system ?

PD: There is no newer version of PHP available in my hosting provider...that sucks! they only offer up to 5.1.6